# How to test angular2 component with injected service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-testing

I folowed official documentation but i still get some errors regarding that some elements appear to be null.

[image]
[image]

```
//test

it('should welcome the user', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //constcontentel.textContent;
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Welcome', '"Welcome ..."');
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test User', 'expected name');
});
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding code as screenshots. If you expect people to help you then please take the time to help them too by providing _properly formatted and readable code_ to save them time reproducing the issue and helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to call method from instance of component inside of test

comp.NameOfMethod();